# Conditional redirect WordPress if referrer URL not match

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, conditional-statements

I Trying to Add Conditional Login if Page number match and of wp_get_referer match wit $value do action but i don't know i stuck some were

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse15677455_redirect' );

function wpse15677455_redirect() {
  $ref = wp_get_referer();
  $value = ('https://mywebsite.com/quotaton/') ;
    if (!is_page(555)) & $ref => $value {
        wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
        // exit; //( I also dont know if need exit if i add this code in function)
    }
 };
```

Also I think of this as solution i don't know is that right or not

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse15677455_redirect' );
 function wpse156774_redirect() {
    $ref = wp_get_referer();
    if (is_page(555)) &&  if (strpos($ref, 'quotaton') !== false) {
        echo 'true';
    }
};
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

After I understood the conditions I figured out the solution:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse1567745555_redirect' );  
function wpse1567745555_redirect() {
  $ref = wp_get_referer();
    if (is_page(227) && $ref == "https://mywebsite/quotaton/") {
        //echo 'Its Working Let it Continue';
    }
    else if (is_page(227) && $ref !== "https://mywebsite/quotaton/"){
        wp_redirect( 'https://mywebsite/sorry/', 301 ); exit;
        // Not Working Let's Redirect and exit 
    }
    else if (!is_page(227)){
          // echo 'Its Not Need Anything Here';
    }
}
```

The above code is useful for WordPress in case you only want to allow a user to access a certain page if they are coming from certain URL.

If have any suggestion please add them.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is not clear to me. But I guess you are looking for this.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse15677455_redirect' );

function wpse15677455_redirect() {

  $value = ('https://mywebsite.com/quotaton/') ;
    if (!is_page(555) & wp_get_referer() !== $value ) {

       wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );

    }
 };
```

Comment: Hi There Thanks for your reply But Some Error ")" it come after $value I Fix that Also I able to manage I figure our better solution which I post as answer Here... Again Thanks for your tim